# Kann das Präfix eines trennbaren Verbs zusammen mit einem weiteren Satzglied ins Vorfeld gezogen werden?

Tags: word-order, separable-verb

In der Süddeutschen Zeitung vom 3. Juni heißt es im Artikel *Auch wenn es weh tut* zur Armenien-Resolution des Bundestages:

> **Den Ton vor** gibt wie so oft und so gerne Norbert Lammert. (Auszeichnung meine)

Mich verwirrt, dass sowohl *den Ton* als auch das Präfix *vor* des trennbaren Verbs *vorgeben* im Vorfeld auftreten. Ich hätte nichts gegen die folgenden Varianten (wobei ich die Erste definitiv gegenüber der Zweiten bevorzugen würde):

> **Den Ton** gibt wie so oft und so gerne Norbert Lammert **vor.**
>
> **Vor** gibt **den Ton** wie so oft und so gerne Norbert Lammert.

Also jeweils nur eines der Beiden im Vorfeld, das Andere an seiner natürlichen Position im Satz.

Ist es grammatikalisch erlaubt, das Präfix *vor* zusammen mit *den Ton* ins Vorfeld zu ziehen, oder ist mein Unbehagen berechtigt und diese Konstruktion eher als »falsch« einzustufen?

Comment: Dein zweites "akzeptables Beispiel" (*vor gibt den Ton*) macht mir Bauchschmerzen. Ich habe dieselbe Übung mit "die Wahl annehmen" gemacht - "Die Wahl an nimmt der Kanzler", "An nimmt die Wahl der Kanzler" ist beides Unsinn. "Die Wahl nimmt der Kanzler an" ist OK. Annahme: Nein lieber nicht.

Comment: Was ist mit _**Den Ton** gibt **vor** wie so oft…_ und _**Den Ton vorgeben** tut wie so oft…_?

Comment: @Crissov "In deinem zweiten Satz ist eine Hupe", hätte meine Deutschlehrerin gesagt. Bei *den Ton vorgeben* tut die ja vielleicht passen...

Comment: @tofro Der Fokus im Deutschunterrichts liegt halt auf der Schriftsprache und da dürfte unzweifelhaft _**Den Ton** gibt … **vor**_ die bevorzugte, für viele sogar die einzig mögliche Variante sein. Mündlich sind Konstrukte mit _tun_ (und _machen_) alles andere als unüblich.

Comment: @tofro: was ist mit "ab geht die Post"?

Comment: @Crissov Erinnerung: Es geht um einen Zeitungsartikel.

Comment: @dirkt Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob "abgehen" (im Sinne deines Satzes) traditionell als ein zusammengesetztes Verb betrachtet werden kann und damit die gleichen Regeln gelten. Ausserdem könnte man das auch als (u.U. sogar lautmalerisches, man denke an die Postkutsche) Idiom betrachten, für das die üblichen sprachlichen Regeln nur eingeschränkt gelten müssen.

Comment: So gut wie alle Grenzfälle im Zusammenhang mit solchen Präfixen hängen vom individuellen Wort ab. "Weh tut es mir kaum noch" ist ziemlich akzeptabel; "Vor gibt den Ton ein anderer" viel weniger. Der Grund ist, daß die Entwicklung von bloßer Kollokation zu genuin trenbarem Verb ein hochproduktiver, noch andauernder Prozeß ist, in dem verschiedene Verben ganz verschiedene Stadien einnehmen.

Comment: Ich stimme vielen von euch zu, dass »Vor gibt den Ton …« deutlich weniger akzeptabel ist als »Den Ton gibt … vor«. Allerdings halte ich es immernoch für besser als »Den Ton vor gibt …«.

Comment: @tofro »Gestern ist die Post abgegangen« ist für mich in Ordnung, demnach betrachte ich das wahrscheinlich schon noch eher als trennbares Verb denn als fixes Idiom. (Und mir gefällt die Hupe =D)

Comment: @tofro: Natürlich ist es ein zusammengesetztes Verb. "Die Post geht ab" und nicht "Die Post abgeht.".

Comment: Ich denke die ursprüngliche Form des Satzes war "Norbert Lammert gibt wie so oft und so gerne den Ton vor." Da dies den "Tonvorgeber" vorweg nimmt und möglicherweise etwas "herablassend" klingt, wurde das kurzerhand umgestellt und das "vor" mitgezogen - Korrekturlesen macht der PC. Weitere valide Möglichkeiten denselben Sachverhalt auszudrücken wären "Wie so oft und so gerne gibt Norbert Lammert den Ton vor." oder "Den Ton gibt wie so oft und so gerne Norbert Lammert vor." Sie unterscheiden sich nur in verschiedenen Spannungsbögen. "Den Ton vor gibt ..." mag richtig sein, klingt aber hölzern.

Comment: @user22338 Das unterschreibe ich dir alles gerne, bis auf den letzten Satz. Ob dieser letzte Satz gestattet ist, oder nicht, darum dreht sich die Frage ;)

Comment: Ich würde das als "nicht gestattet" werten. Ähnliche Konstellationen gibt es mit "angeben", "aufgeben", "durchgeben", "vorgeben", "zugeben", "vorbeugen", "vorschützen", "vortäuschen" - Präposition steht bei allen Konjugationen hinter dem Wortstamm: "ich gebe durch", nicht "ich durchgebe" oder "er gab auf", nicht "er aufgab". weitere: "wir geben zu", "sie beugt vor", ... Die Begründung fällt mir schwer, eine Regel kann ich nicht finden. Mein Gefühl sagt mir, dass der Wortstamm den entscheidenden Hinweis zur Aktivität gibt, nicht die Präposition. ;)

Comment: Ich würde das zweite Beispiel nur akzeptieren, wenn mit einer anderen Präposition kontrastiert würde. Hier fällt mir keine sinnvolle ein, ich meine aber so etwas wie: "Vor gibt den Ton Lammert, ab gibt ihn jedoch Bammert"

Answer (score 6):

Soweit mir bekannt ist, gestatten die derzeit geltenden Grammatikregel diese halbe Trennung eines trennbaren Verbes nicht. Mit »halbe Trennung« meine ich, dass nur ein Leerzeichen in das Verb eingefügt wird (»vorgibt« wird zu »vor gibt«), ohne das Präfix dann an einen anderen Platz zu stellen.

Ungetrennt:

> Ilse überholt den Bus.
>   Manfred umfährt den Baum.
>   Lampert vorgibt den Ton.

»Halbe Trennung«:

> Ilse über holt den Bus.
>   Manfred um fährt den Baum.
>   Lampert vor gibt den Ton.

Trennung:

> Ilse holt den Bus über.
>   Manfred fährt den Baum um.
>   Lampert gibt den Ton vor.

»Überholen« ist kein trennbares Verb, daher ist das Beispiel mit Ilse nur in der ersten Version richtig, die beiden anderen sind falsch. »Vorgeben« hingegen ist ein trennbares Verb, daher ist in diesem Fall nur die dritte Version richtig.

»Umfahren« hat zwei Bedeutungen. Als untrennbares Verb (wovon »*die Umfahrung*« abgeleitet ist) bedeutet es: Um etwas herum fahren:

> »Die Verkehrsteilnehmer werden gebeten, den gesperrten Bereich großräumig **zu umfahren**.«

Als trennbares Verb bedeutet das Wort aber: Etwas beim Fahren mit den Fahrzeug so heftig berühren, dass es umfällt.

> Walter hat gestern versucht, diesen hässlichen Strauch **umzufahren**.

Wegen dieser Doppel-Bedeutung sind sowohl »Manfred umfährt den Baum« als auch »Manfred fährt den Baum um« richtig, aber die beiden Sätze stellen zwei ganz unterschiedliche Ereignisse dar.

In keinem Fall ist der Satz mit der halben Trennung richtig. In dem Beispiel mit Manfred und dem Baum ist sogar unklar, was der Satz bedeuten soll, weil es eben zwei Möglichkeiten gibt den Satz zu korrigieren, die ohne Kontext gleich wahrscheinlich erscheinen.

Daher wage ich diese Aussage:

> Der Satz »*Den Ton vor gibt wie so oft und so gerne Norbert Lammert.*« ist grammatisch falsch.

---

**ABER**

Ich beobachte aber, dass die deutsche Sprache derzeit einen Wandel durchmacht. Die deutsche Grammatik wird stark von logischen Klammern geprägt. Damit meine ich Teile eines Redeflusses, die zwar logisch zusammengehören (also eine Idee bilden), aber von anderen Ideen unterbrochen werden.

Ein Beispiel:

> Inge wollte die Katze, die auf dem Sofa lag, streicheln.

Noch in meiner Schulzeit (1970er) wäre es undenkbar gewesen, diesen Satz so zu formulieren:

> Inge wollte die Katze streicheln, die auf dem Sofa lag.

Heute ist es ganz normal solche Klammern zu vermeiden, indem das Verb zwischen das zu beschreibende Nomen und den Attributsatz geschoben wird. Ich weiß nicht, ob diese Variante grammatisch korrekt ist, aber umgangssprachlich ist sie weit verbreitet. Sie macht den Satz leichter verständlich, weil man sich nicht mehr so viele logische Klammern merken muss, wie die XXL-Version meines Beispiels zeigt:

> Inge wollte die Katze, die auf dem Sofa, das ich von Markus, der gleich gegenüber wohnt, gekauft habe, lag, streicheln.
>   Inge wollte die Katze streicheln, die auf dem Sofa lag, das ich von Markus gekauft habe, der gleich gegenüber wohnt.

Wie gesagt: Das Aufheben von logischen Klammern, die von Attributsätzen herrühren, ist heute schon alltägliche Praxis.

Das Aufheben von Klammern, die durch trennbare Verben entstehen, beginnt sich gerade erst zu entwickeln. Das in den Kommentaren zur Frage erwähnte

> Ab geht die Post.

ist nur ein Beispiel, das im Alltag bereits Anwendung findet.

Ich glaube, dass die Tatsache, das große Teile der deutschsprachigen Bevölkerung mindestens eine Fremdsprache (meist Englisch) sprechen, hier einen großen Einfluss hat. Deutsche Muttersprachler sind aufgrund ihrer Fremdsprachkenntnisse bereits mit anderen Blaupausen, nach denen Sätze gebaut werden können, vertraut. Ich glaube, dass das die Bereitschaft erhöht, auch ins Deutsche alternative Satzbaupläne einfließen zu lassen. Insbesondere dann, wenn diese Alternativen es einfacher machen, den Inhalt eines Satzes zu erfassen.

Ich traue mich daher vorherzusagen, dass wir in den nächsten Jahren und Jahrzehnten Sätze wie den hier diskutierten häufiger lesen werden, und dass dann auch die offiziellen Grammatikregeln diese Möglichkeit erlauben werden.

Answer (score 1):

In der Linguistik hat man unter dem Begriff *partial verb phrase fronting* Beispiele wie das folgende diskutiert:

> *Ein Märchen erzählen* wird er seiner Tochter.

(Wenn man nach dem Satz googelt, sind alle Treffer aus der Fachliteratur.)

Das Ausgangsbeispiel kann man parallel dazu analysieren, als Voranstellung einer verbalen Partikel zusammen mit einem abhängigen Element. Weitere Belege zu dieser Art von Voranstellung finden sich in Stefan Müller, *Complex Predicates: Verbal Complexes, Resultative Constructions, and Particle Verbs in German*, S. 280-292 ([Seite des Buches](https://hpsg.hu-berlin.de/~stefan/Pub/complex.html) oder direkt das [PDF](https://hpsg.hu-berlin.de/~stefan/Pub/complex.pdf)).

> *Mit der Schwarzmalerei einher* gehe die sinkende Sterbe- und Geburtenfreudigkeit.
>
> *Damit zusammen* hängt auch, daß bestimmte Konstituenten leichter voranstellbar sind.
>
> *Gut zurecht* kommt derjenige, der das Leben mit all seinen Überraschungen
>   annimmt.
>
> *So gut klar* komm ich nicht.

Man findet im Internet auch einige Treffer für Sätze wie die folgenden:

> *Den Vogel ab* schoß übrigens wieder einmal Präsident Donald Trump.
>
> *Noch nicht ganz fest* steht, ob es im Jubiläumsjahr endlich wieder einmal eine Großkirmes in der Stadt geben wird.

(Inspiriert von den Beispielen 660 und 661 im genannten Buch.)